# How to convert a character column into date using as.POSIXct?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I have a  problem. I  have  a data frame (data.in) with 3 columns (date| wd |ws ) and  using `str()` command gives me character for  column "date". Ok, I said I will use function : `as.POSIXct(data.in$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )`. It doesn't give `NA` values but  the  date column remains character format and  it  doesn't convert to date format.

```
data.in <- read.csv(file = "/home/vlad/Documents/vldZ/R_meteo/20130101.csv",
col.names = c("date","hr","ws.80","wd.80"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data.in$data <- paste(data.in$date,data.in$hr) data.in[1:2] <- NULL 

colnames(data.in)[3] <- "date" 
as.Date(data.in$data,format = "%m/%d/%Y ") 
as.POSIXct(data.in$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" ) #### my code
```

Comment: data.in <- read.csv(file = "/home/vlad/Documents/vldZ/R_meteo/20130101.csv",
                    col.names = c("date","hr","ws.80","wd.80"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data.in$data <- paste(data.in$date,data.in$hr)
data.in[1:2] <- NULL
colnames(data.in)[3] <- "date"
as.Date(data.in$data,format = "%m/%d/%Y ")
as.POSIXct(data.in$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" ) #### my code

Comment: Add data to your question not as a comment. Use `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: do you just type `as.POSIXct(data.in$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )` or `data.in$date <- as.POSIXct(data.in$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" )`. Only the second will store the data

Comment: How do you know that "the date column remains character format and it doesn't convert to date format"? Have you checked the class of the column?

Comment: Thanks Chelmy88. It  works with dolar signs. That store my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use different functions to make your time/date variables. Pay attention to the `typeof` (*i.e.*, data storage mode in the memory) and `class` (*i.e.,* object classes):

```
date1 <- as.Date(
  c("2019-01-01 14:22","2019-01-01 16:08", "2019-01-01 07:16"), 
  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
  )
> typeof(date1)
[1] "double"
> class(date1)
[1] "Date"


date2 <- as.POSIXct(
  c("2019-01-01 14:22","2019-01-01 16:08", "2019-01-01 07:16"), 
  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
)
> typeof(date2)
[1] "double"
> class(date2)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 


date3 <-  strptime(
  c("2019-01-01 14:22","2019-01-01 16:08", "2019-01-01 07:16"), 
  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
)
> typeof(date3)
[1] "list"
> class(date3)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

They may be shown as in double quotes `" "`:

```
[1] "2019-01-01 14:22:00 +0330" "2019-01-01 16:08:00 +0330"
[3] "2019-01-01 07:16:00 +0330"
```

But they do not have a `character` typeof.